# Why doesn't this CNN model need fetures for reducing overfitting?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, nvidia

[image: model]I found this CNN model by Nvidia [end-to-end-deeplearning](https://images.nvidia.com/content/tegra/automotive/images/2016/solutions/pdf/end-to-end-dl-using-px.pdf) and with training this model, I'm wondering why this model doesn't need to have dropout layers to reduce overfitting. Neither, this doesn't have activation function.

I know we can tune the number of epochs and it reduces overfitting. 
I'm curious why this model works better without those layers?